# usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed

Tags: linux, usb

I get this over and over in syslog, but can't identify what device its trying to disable. In fact I can't identify what bus 4 is. lsusb -t shows

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
|__ Port 6: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
```

There is never a device on the bus. As far as the code around the disable in syslog it varies a bit, but here is a sample

```
Mar  1 15:09:46 orac kernel: [1734088.436718] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  1 15:09:46 orac kernel: [1734088.441235] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  1 15:09:46 orac kernel: [1734088.678602] usb 4-6.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Mar  1 15:10:34 orac kernel: [1734137.109047] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Mar  1 15:10:34 orac kernel: [1734137.113527] usb 4-6.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Mar  1 15:10:35 orac kernel: [1734137.355055] usb 4-6.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
```

This is an HP Z230 running Ubuntu 22.04